# What is a storage cell?

Tags: ink, storage

Somewhat noob question:

I see the term storage cell talked about a lot on here (mostly regarding `Mapping` and `Lazy`), however I cannot find any documentation about it.

What exactly is a storage cell?
Are they a set size? If so what is the size? Does the size vary based on individual pallet implementation?
Is there any way to access the size of a storage cell in `ink`?
What happens if a storage cell's size is exceeded? Is the data split across two cells instead?

I *assume* a storage cell is a record in a database on a node, is that correct?

Assuming storage costs are proportional to the number of records used in the db by a smart contract, it would be handy to know the size of the storage cells so I can optimise the smart contract storage accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: [ink! storage documentation](https://use.ink/datastructures/overview)

To answer your questions:

Storage in ink! is organized as a key/value database. So for each unique key, you have one unique cell (which can contain a value). The values are SCALE encoded, and the maximum length of a value is defined by the pallet. If this value is exceeded, you will get a `DispatchError`, and the contract execution will be trapped (reverted). The default value in substrate/frame/contracts is 16 * 1024 bytes.